# How to fetch apex:input field value into extension class

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I am trying to get the value that user enters for the Start Date and Team Name fields into the Extension class as mentioned below but i am getting Null. Could someone please help.

VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Tracker__c" extensions="TrackerExtension">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="View Details">
                <apex:inputField label="Start Date" required="true" value="{!Tracker__c.Sprint_Start_Date__c}" id="DatefieldVal" /> 
                <apex:inputField label="Team Name" required="true" value="{!Tracker__c.Team_Names__c}" id="TeamfieldVal"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
<apex:page>
```

Extension Class:

```
public with sharing class TrackerExtension {
    public Date DatefieldVal {get;set;}
    public String TeamfieldVal {get;set;}


    public TrackerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    system.debug('ssDate'+ ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('DatefieldVal'));
    system.debug('team'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('TeamfieldVal'));

    }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please use the `{}` tool in the editor to format your code so contributors can read it, and make sure to only use relevant tags - this question is not related to `community` or `salesforce1-app`.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed, could you suggest me which tags to use to get answer for my question.

Comment: I have tagged your question `apex`, `visualforce`, and `controller-extension`, which seems to me to sum up what you are working with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters()` call allows you to access *URL parameters* supplied to your page. It has nothing to do with values bound to components on your page.

Your input fields are bound to field values on the object instance `Tracker__c` that is managed by the standard controller:

```
<apex:inputField label="Start Date" required="true" value="{!Tracker__c.Sprint_Start_Date__c}" id="DatefieldVal" /> 
<apex:inputField label="Team Name" required="true" value="{!Tracker__c.Team_Names__c}" id="TeamfieldVal"/>
```

Your constructor receives a reference to the standard controller:

```
public TrackerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
```

which it is typical to save in an instance variable, e.g.,

```
private ApexPages.StandardController controller; 
public TrackerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}
```

Then, in your action methods, you can access the record managed by the standard controller by calling `controller.getRecord()`. You probably won't be doing this in your constructor, however, as the user will not have had a chance to interact with the page and populate any values at this point.

Note that while you can give Ids to your components in Visualforce, your server-side controller access is through value binding. You won't make calls based on the component Id in Apex to access their values, as you might when working in client-side JavaScript.

Comment: If i want to capture the dynamic data that the user enters like in a form what changes do i need to make in my code so that i will be able to retrieve the values into the extension class. I also have an option of capturing these field values after clicking Submit button, could i use a method for Submit in which i can access the field values.

Comment: Yes. You need to do as I mention above: capture the standard controller and access its instance of the record with `getRecord()`.

Comment: Thanks it is working.

Comment: @Nag if this answer solved your issue please consider marking it as accepted. It will reward the poster and yourself and indicate the question has a useful answer for others with similar issue